# Get all cache in ASP.NET Core 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

The version is rc1.
In my old project there are codes like

```
System.Web.Caching.Cache c = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache;
System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator cacheEnumerator = c.GetEnumerator();
while (cacheEnumerator.MoveNext())
{....}
```

In core 1 I use `IMemoryCache` and I can get cache by key like

```
var c = this._memoryCache;
var data = c.Get("data");
```

I want to make a view to list all cache. How can I get all cache in Core 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source of ASP.NET Core's MemoryCache implementation on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs), 
you can see that the class doesn't expose any functionality to scan or iterate the list of cache entries.

The closest you can do is use reflection to read the inner cache dictionary:

```
 private readonly Dictionary<object, CacheEntry> _entries;
```

Wrap the reflection code in an extension method that accepts an `IMemoryCache` and returns an `IEnumerable<CacheEntry>` and you're good - but there are several risks involved:

1. This implementation is specific to the current, pre-release version of ASP.NET CORE. This could change in newer versions, since it's an internal implementation detail and not part of the contract.
2. This is specific to the implementation of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache, which is just *one* implementation of `IMemoryCache`. You might replace it with a different implementation one day, which will break.
3. The implementation contains a set of locks to manage concurrent access to the cache entries. If you iterate over the inner dictionary directly, you can run into concurrency errors when you try to read an entry while it's being updated. The first step is to *never* update the cache entry directly, and always go through `IMemoryCache`'s methods, but even then, there's a risk.

Knowing the risks, though, you can go forth and get your job done.

Comment: When I try this, I get the folllowing error: ['CacheEntry' is inaccessible due to its protection level].  I'm using 1.0.1 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

Comment: Search for "reflection private members". You need to specify specific BindingFlags to access private members.

Comment: Hi Avner.  Sorry, I wasn't clear on my error.  Using the following code: var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic; var entries = this.MemoryCache.GetType().GetField("_entries", flags).GetValue(this.MemoryCache); I get a reference to this object.  Using WATCH, it says the type is "object {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<object, Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheEntry>}".  The problem is when I try to cast it: var dic = entries as Dictionary<object, CacheEntry>; Here I get a compile error saying CacheEntry is internal and inaccessible.  Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Solved:  var dic = entries as IDictionary;  Then it's simply a use of: foreach (DictionaryEntry cacheEntry in dic) {... }

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using reflection you could also add to a Dictionary every time you add to the cache and maintain it with callbacks from cache policies. Less dependent on the .net `MemoryCache` if you handle it this way. Would probably have some concurrency issues with the Dictionary, but as long as it is locked on updates and deletes it should do fine.

Comment: In .net github I see there is a issue about this problem so I think MS will improve this.